# Solve for a,b,c,d,e belongs to real numbers.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Solve the following system of equations for real numbers a, b, c, d, e.
$$
3a = (b + c + d)^3,\\
3b = (c + d + e)^3,\\
3c = (d + e + a)^3,\\
3d = (e + a + b)^3,\\
3e = (a + b + c)^3.
$$

Comment: Please look up Mathjax/Latex, and format your question properly next time. You are more likely to get answers if you show what you have tried, and what are you exactly struggling with

Comment: Do you want _a_ solution, or do you want _all_ solutions? Because $a=b=c=d=e \in {0, 1/3, -1/3}$ work as solutions.

Comment: All solutions are i want to find

Comment: If not other solutions possible then want toprove so

Comment: You can prove that $a = b = c = d=e$ by noting $3a < 3b \implies b+c +d < c+d +e \imples b < e \implies c+d+e < a+b +c$ ... etc. will lead to a contradiction.

Comment: No wonder the problem looked familiar. This is a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1809950/cyclic-system-of-cubic-equations-in-5-variables).

Answer (score 2):

Notice the map $x \mapsto x^3$ is strictly increasing. In other words, 
$x > y \iff x^3 > y^3$.

Consider what happens when $a > b$, we have

$$
\begin{array}{cll}
a > b 
&\implies  (b+c+d)^3 > (c+d+e)^3 
&\implies b > e\\
\large\Downarrow\\
a > b  > e 
& \stackrel{a > e}{\implies} (b+c+d)^3 > (a+b+c)^3 
& \implies d > a\\
\large\Downarrow\\
d > a > b > e 
& \stackrel{d > e}{\implies} (e + a + b)^3 > (a + b + c)^3
& \implies e > c\\
\large\Downarrow\\
d > a > b > e > c 
& \stackrel{b > c}{\implies} (c + d + e)^3 > (d + e + a)^3
& \implies c > a\\
\large\Downarrow\\
d > a > b > e > c > a
\end{array}
$$
This leads to a contradiction that $a > a$.
By a similar argument, if $a < b$, we find another contradiction $a < a$.
As a result, any solution of the set of equations must have $a = b$.

Notice the set of equations is invariant under cyclic permutation $a \to b  \to c \to d \to e \to a$.
This means any solution of the set of equations must satisfy $a = b = c = d = e$.  Let $\lambda$ be this common value. The set of $5$ equations reduces to

$$3\lambda = (\lambda + \lambda + \lambda)^3 = 27\lambda^3
\quad\iff\quad 3\lambda(1 - 9\lambda^2) = 0 \quad\iff\quad \lambda = 0\text{ or } \pm \frac13$$

The given set of equations have $3$ and only $3$ real solutions:

$$a = b = c = d = e = 0\text{ or } \pm\frac13$$

Answer (score 1):

Wolog $a \le b \le c \le d \le e$.  Suppose $a < e$

Then $3a < 3e$ so $(b+c+d)^3 < (a+b+c)^3$ so $b+c +d < a+b+c$ and $d < a$ which is a contradiction of $a \le b \le c \le d \le e$. So $a = e$ and $a \le b \le c \le d\le e = a$ implies:

$a= b = c = d = e$.

And $3a = (3a)^3$ so $27a^3 - 3a = 3a(3a+1)(3a -1) = 0$ so $a = 0$ or  $a =\pm \frac 13$

Answer (score 0):

The system of equation is symmetric for a, b, c, d and e; If we suppose:

$a=b=c=d=e$ , we have:

$3a =(3a)^3 ⇒  27 a^3 = 3 a ⇒  a^2 =1/9 ⇒ a =  ± 1/3$ or:

$ a=b=c=d=e =  ± 1/3$

So that for each equation we have:

$ 3 ({ ± 1/3}) = ( ± 1/3  ± 1/3 ± 1/3)^3 = ± 1$

Comment: You can't conclude that the variables are equal.  Some solutions have that property, but not necessarily all.  Here it turns out to be true.

Comment: Symetric wouldn't mean they are equal.  It would mean if $a=x$ is a solution than $b=x$ would also be a soultion.